# how to pass my id value to other php file when i login

Tags: php, mysql

this is my checklogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="lecturer"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword

$myid=$_POST['myid'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myid = stripslashes($myid);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myid = mysql_real_escape_string($myid);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ID='$myid' and password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1 ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_session['myid'] = 'myid';
$_session['mypassword'] = 'mypassword';
$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($info['id'] == 0){
    header("location: webpage.php");
}
else if ($info['id'] == 100) {
    header("location: lecturer_user.php?myid=$myid");
}
else if ($info['id'] == 102) {
    header("location: lecturer_user.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
header ("refresh:5; url=main_login.php");

}
}
ob_end_flush();
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <table>
<th><a href="main_login.php?pressed=back">Back</a></th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my lecturer_user.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<a href=\"drop.php?myid=".$_SESSION['myid']."\">drop</a>";
?>
```

this is my drop.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
mysql_select_db('lecturer');



$myid = $_GET["myid"];

$query = 'SELECT persons.ID , persons.FirstName , user_subject.subject
FROM persons
INNER JOIN user_subject
ON persons.ID = user_subject.ID
WHERE persons.ID = '.$myid.' ORDER BY user_subject.subject';

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>


<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Drop subject</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Subject</strong></td>

</tr>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <?php echo $row['ID']; ?> </td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <?php echo $row['subject']; ?> </td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="submit" value="Delete Checked Rows" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="user_subject.php?pressed=subject">Back</a></td>


</tr>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
$del_query = "DELETE FROM user_subject WHERE ID IN (";
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
$del_query .= "'" . (int) $data . "',";
}
$del_query .= "'')";
mysql_query($del_query) or die(mysql_error());
header("Location:" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}



mysql_close()


?>
</table>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

what i am trying to do is when i login as id = 100 it will lead to lecturer_user.php?myid=100
and the main problem is when i am in lecturer_user i wanted the session id to recognize as id=100 so each user have their own unique id
and when i click the view which is testing.php it will redirect it to be testing.php?myid=100 so that i can view only id = 100 subjects only not others.

i wanted is when user id 100 login can only view their own profile.
thank you

thank you

Comment: erm.. i think i already solve it myself thank you very much to you guys for helping me 
i change to session $_SESSION to capital and i just add session start in my lecturer_user.php
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are setting

```
 $_session['myid'] = 'myid';
```

use

```
 $_session['myid'] = $info['id'];
```

in  checklogin.php

Answer (score 0):

When login success set a Session variable with id of logged in user as :

```
$_SESSION['myid'] = $info['id'];
```

So that you can access to the logged in user in all pages until you unset it as

```
$_SESSION['myid'];
```

Make sure you dont forget to unset session when user log out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$_session['myid'] = $myid ;
$_session['mypassword'] = $mypassword ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **checklogin.php** set your session as:

```
$_SESSION['myid'] = $myid;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
```

Also remove `session_start();` from your **lecturer_user.php** as you have already started the session in **checklogin.php**

Comment: the error i am still getting is Notice: Undefined variable: _session in C:\wamp\www\Project\lecturer_user.php on line 3 after i login using my main_login.php after the changes

Comment: `$_SESSION` is in caps.

Comment: after i change to all to $_SESSION it still the same Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\Project\lecturer_user.php on line 3 
is it the session didnt pass the value???

Comment: After assigning the value to session as i mentioned above, did you change the line `header("location: lecturer_user.php?myid=$myid");` to `header("location: lecturer_user.php?myid=".$_SESSION['myid']);`